# Why not to interact with the DOM directly in Angular?

Tags: angular, dom

I have read that it is not wise to interact with the DOM directly both for security and performance. Avoiding using syntax like below to select Elements.

```
const itemToManipulate = document.getElementById('example');
```

So I read a good work around is to use ElementRef Directive.
But go on to find the Angular Documents advise against this because of tight coupling, what is tight coupling?

[Found in documentation here](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef)

I settled for using a ViewChild, like so...

```
@ViewChild('itemToManipulate') public item: ElementRef<any>;
```

Does this lead to any unwanted behaviour I should be concerned about (security / performance wise) and is there a best practice for interacting with the DOM, or should this not be done within Angular (6 / 7)?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Could you also add the links that you referred on the Angular Docs to the OP?

Comment: Highly recommend to watch [Can't Touch This! What not to do to the DOM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qWmqiYDrnDc)

Comment: in addition to @PankajParkar's video which you should definitely watch, there's a big security risk in directly manipulating the dom, via renderer or native, a manual sanitation is required on many cases. so in short, don't go that way. stick to the angular way of doing stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular uses [Lifecycle Hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) that determine how and when components will be rendered and updated:

> A component has a lifecycle managed by Angular.
>
> Angular creates it, renders it, creates and renders its children, checks it when its data-bound properties change, and destroys it before removing it from the DOM.

Direct DOM access or manipulation can corrupt these lifecycle hooks, leading to unexpected behavior of your whole app.

**[Tight coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming))** means that components (not Angular components but any parts of a program or system) highly depend on each other. In the Angular context, changing a component's state (e. g. variables) directly influences its rendering. Thus, if you access a DOM element directly with `ElementRef`, you cannot run your component code in a web worker (to use multi-threading for example).