# Get an element by ID in Angular 7 component (TypeScript) and use its attributes in component

Tags: angular, html, typescript

We can use the standard Javascript method to get the element by its id:

```
document.getElementById("dataBlock").innerHTML = "";
```

In Angular however, the preferred way to refer to an element is with a template reference variable:

```
<div #dataBlock></div>
<button (click)="dataBlock.innerHTML = ''">Clear content</button>
```

That variable also allows to access the element in code with the help of @ViewChild:

```
@ViewChild("dataBlock") block: ElementRef;

clearContent() {
  this.block.nativeElement.innerHTML = "";
}
```

My question is that, what would be the impact of above code on performance and memory in an angular application.

Comment: Are you specifically asking that would the impact / performance be of this line of code `this.block.nativeElement.innerHTML = "";` ?

Comment: [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53451918/why-not-to-interact-with-the-dom-directly-in-angular), I asked a similar question without much luck.

Comment: @JonasPraem I am asking it generally. Not specifically asking for that line.

Comment: @dince12, I read the same as you mentioned in your question and that's why i am asking here it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the outcome of those 2 lines of code are essentially doing the same thing. The reason for doing it the 'Angular way' is that Angular applications are not always meant to be ran in a browser. For example you can run Angular in a web worker which doesn't have direct access to the DOM.

Another reason is that it is a bit cleaner to have a component reference to a specific element instead of doing getElementById every time you need to access the element.

> My question is that, what would be the impact of above code on performance and memory in an angular application.

Angular gets compiled to javascript so in an Angular SPA this doesn't have any big performance impact. If you want to measure exact performance / memory usage, I would recommend using an extension like [lighthouse](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/). Memory & performance optimisation in Angular is not so much about using the Angular framework, but how you divide your modules, how you lazyload and most important in a SPA - the initial load time. I recommend sticking to the Angular framework and let Angular take care of compile optimisation. You won't safe any measurable time by using getElementById over ViewChild.

Made a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b7sepu) measuring the time it takes to perform `this.block.nativeElement.innerHTML = "";` - it comes out as 0 milliseconds.

Comment: Thanks Jonas, and 

No, I do not mean to say or ask for this particular line

    this.block.nativeElement.innerHTML = ""

I ask it generally. Means How much it could be costly if I use it so frequently in my application.

Comment: I really want to help you, but that is a very broad question

Comment: true, its really a very broad question. I am at the initial level of my project and want to consider such points to avoid the performance and / or memory issues in my project at later stages.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: If you are using the Angular framework, stick to the framework guidelines. If you feel like using raw javascript i suggest avoiding frameworks like React or Angular. You are gonna get weird race conditions and behaviours if you mix and match.

Comment: Thanks for nice suggestions and I agree with we must follow the framework guidelines.