# What is the impact if we use the jquery plugins in angular 7?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular7

I'm new to angular. Some forums and tutorials show how to integrate jquery plugins in angular. Actually there are plenty of jquery plugins. I used a lot of jquery plugin in my previous projects which were implemented *only* in jquery. So I would like to get that feel (colors,UI, animation...) into my angular 7 project. But in the middle, I'm worrying that some forums say "**Don't mix jquery plugins with angular**"

So may I import jquery plugins inside angular? Will it be a problem? For Eg : [Datatable](https://datatables.net/) has a lot of function where I need most. [Jquery Confirm Master](https://craftpip.github.io/jquery-confirm/) gives a better UI. And there are a lot of API calls also. If I need to use these kind of jquery plugins, what can I do?

Comment: What is your reason to use Angular in the first place, if you are going to stick to Jquery ? Get into this decade and modernize your abilities with a modern framework.

Comment: @JonasPraem Im new to angular, So I would like to know whether I will get any issues if I use jquery plugins into angular..

Comment: If you have the time, learn how to do it typescript. Once a few concepts start clicking, you will enjoy it. Personal Opinion.

Comment: AFAIK you can use angular and jquery, purists will indeed advice against this as jquery defeats the purpose of angular by directly manipulating the DOM, which you basically want angular to be in charge of (a bad practice IMO as well). Some plugins that you mention in your question can be found implemented in angular with no usage of jquery.

Comment: To answer this we need to know the reason you want to use angular in the first place. What value points of angular are you looking to utilize?

Comment: Depend on you use case, you can do all that tweaks in Typescript

Comment: @JonasPraem I didnt implement any structure when I used jquery. This is the time I should get the knowledge of  trending framework, working of SPA. Thats why I need more clarification.

Comment: My personal advice: move away from jquery and never look back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some core reasons you shouldn't access the DOM directly in Angular (as you do with Jquery). I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54291940/get-an-element-by-id-in-angular-7-component-typescript-and-use-its-attributes/54292608#54292608)

Angular is a fully blown framework where you shouldn't differ from the 'Angular way'. There are several reasons for this. For one your code will become very complicated in the way it works. Some things you do in Jquery is very hideous compared to how simple you can implement the same thing with Angular. Another reason is that Angular applications are not always meant to be ran in a browser. For example you can run Angular in a web worker, which doesn't have direct access to the DOM. Your components will become dependent on Jquery when there is no need to, which might hurt you if you want to reuse those components in other Angular applications.

Your value point for sticking to Jquery is that you can reuse that code. To that I will say that you should rewrite those components for your Angular application so you can later reuse those components in other Angular applications. Modernize / rewrite your components now, so you have optimized clean Angular components. You will quickly find that your Jquery code is overly complicated compared to how you do similar things in the Angular framework.