# Page is not displaying properly until manually refresh Angular

Tags: angular, routes

I m facing very strange issue. My angular application page is displaying properly. It seems its not fully loaded, and when I m manually reloading/refreshing the page, its loading fine.

Here is the full scenario. I created a login page which displays perfectly and working as expected. After login I m navigating to my dashboard page which is not showing properly, seems half loaded, but when manually refresh its work fine. After inspecting elements, I found that the contents of dashboard is there but not showing properly. there is no any error in console as well

Here is my app-routing.module.ts code:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { MainLayoutComponent } from './main-layout/main-layout.component';

const routes: Routes = [

  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'dashboard', component: MainLayoutComponent },
  { path: '', pathMatch: "full", redirectTo: 'dashboard' },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

And here is my login.component.ts

```
declare var $: any;
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Common } from '../Common/common';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private router: Router) { }

  form: any;

  submitModel: any = {
    username: "",
    password: ""
  };

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = $('#myloginform').parsley();

    localStorage.clear();
  }

  SubmitForm() {
    if ($("#myloginform").parsley().validate()) {
      $(".preloader").show();
      this.httpClient.post<any>(Common.APIUrl + "login", this.submitModel, { withCredentials: true }).subscribe(
        {
          next: data => {
            console.log(data);
            localStorage.setItem("token", data.result);
            this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
          },
          error: error => {
            console.error(error);
          },
          complete: function () {
            console.log("complete");
            $(".preloader").hide();
          }
        }
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Here is my main-layout.component.ts

```
declare var $: any;
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Common } from '../Common/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main-layout',
  templateUrl: './main-layout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main-layout.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class MainLayoutComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("MainLayoutComponent - on init called")
  }


  Logout() {
    $(".preloader").show();
    this.httpClient.get<any>(Common.APIUrl + "logout", { withCredentials: true }).subscribe(
      {
        next: data => {
          localStorage.clear();
          this.router.navigate(['login']);
        },
        error: error => {
          console.error(error);
        },
        complete: function () {
          $(".preloader").hide();
        }
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Currently facing like this:
[image]

Expected result:
[image]

Additional Info: when I m logging out, its navigating to Login page properly. I have added all references of jQuery/Bootstrap + additional plugin in my index html page.

I m new to angular and this is my first question in StackOverflow. Please forgive me, if I couldn't explain better. Thanks in advance

I removed the content from Dashboard and just added one <h1> tag. it is displaying

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow">
  <base href="/">
  <title>Employee App</title>
  <!-- Favicon icon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="assets/images/favicon.png">
  <!-- Custom CSS -->
  <link href="assets/dist/css/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="assets/dist/css/style.extended.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

  <app-root></app-root>

  <script src="assets/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap tether Core JavaScript -->
  <script src="assets/libs/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/libs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <!--Parsley -->
  <script src="assets/extra-libs/parsley/parsley.js"></script>
  <!-- apps -->
  <script src="assets/dist/js/app.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/dist/js/app.init.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/dist/js/app-style-switcher.js"></script>
  <!-- slimscrollbar scrollbar JavaScript -->
  <script src="assets/libs/perfect-scrollbar/dist/perfect-scrollbar.jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/libs/jquery-sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
  <!--Wave Effects -->
  <script src="assets/dist/js/waves.js"></script>
  <!--Menu sidebar -->
  <script src="assets/dist/js/sidebarmenu.js"></script>
  <!--Custom JavaScript -->
  <script src="assets/dist/js/feather.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/dist/js/custom.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

MainLayout.component.html

```
<div id="main-wrapper">
  <header class="topbar">
    <nav class="navbar top-navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="nav-toggler waves-effect waves-light d-block d-md-none" href=""><i class="ti-menu ti-close"></i></a>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">
          <b class="logo-icon">
            <img src="../assets/images/logo-icon.png" alt="homepage" class="dark-logo" />
            <img src="../assets/images/logo-light-icon.png" alt="homepage" class="light-logo" />
          </b>
          <span class="logo-text">
            <img src="../assets/images/logo-text.png" alt="homepage" class="dark-logo" />
            <img src="../assets/images/logo-light-text.png" class="light-logo" alt="homepage" />
          </span>
        </a>
        <a class="topbartoggler d-block d-md-none waves-effect waves-light" href="" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"><i class="ti-more"></i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item d-none d-md-block"><a class="nav-link sidebartoggler waves-effect waves-light" href="" data-sidebartype="mini-sidebar"><i class="icon-arrow-left-circle"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle text-muted waves-effect waves-dark pro-pic" href="" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><img src="../assets/images/users/1.jpg" alt="user" class="rounded-circle" width="31"></a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right user-dd animated flipInY">
              <div class="d-flex no-block align-items-center p-3 mb-2 border-bottom">
                <div class=""><img src="../assets/images/users/1.jpg" alt="user" class="rounded" width="80"></div>
                <div class="ml-2">
                  <h4 class="mb-0">Steave Jobs</h4>
                  <p class=" mb-0">varun@gmail.com</p>
                  <a href="profile.html" class="btn btn-rounded btn-danger btn-sm">View Profile</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="" (click)="Logout()"><i class="fa fa-power-off mr-1 ml-1"></i> Logout</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <aside class="left-sidebar">
    <div class="scroll-sidebar">
      <nav class="sidebar-nav">
        <ul id="sidebarnav">
          <li class="nav-small-cap"><i class="mdi mdi-dots-horizontal"></i> <span class="hide-menu">Personal</span></li>
          <li class="sidebar-item">
            <a href="" class="sidebar-link waves-effect waves-dark" aria-expanded="false"><i data-feather="link" class="feather-icon"></i><span class="hide-menu">Sample Link</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="sidebar-item">
            <a class="sidebar-link has-arrow waves-effect waves-dark" href="" aria-expanded="false"><i data-feather="map" class="feather-icon"></i><span class="hide-menu">Sample Link</span></a>
            <ul aria-expanded="false" class="collapse  first-level">
              <li class="sidebar-item"><a href="map-google.html" class="sidebar-link"><i class="mdi mdi-adjust"></i><span class="hide-menu">Google Maps</span></a></li>
              <li class="sidebar-item"><a href="map-vector.html" class="sidebar-link"><i class="mdi mdi-adjust"></i><span class="hide-menu">Vector Maps</span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="sidebar-item">
            <a class="sidebar-link has-arrow waves-effect waves-dark" href="" aria-expanded="false"><i data-feather="git-pull-request" class="feather-icon"></i><span class="hide-menu">Multi level dd</span></a>
            <ul aria-expanded="false" class="collapse first-level">
              <li class="sidebar-item"><a href="" class="sidebar-link"><i class="mdi mdi-octagram"></i><span class="hide-menu">item 1.1</span></a></li>
              <li class="sidebar-item"><a href="" class="sidebar-link"><i class="mdi mdi-octagram"></i><span class="hide-menu">item 1.2</span></a></li>
              <li class="sidebar-item">
                <a class="has-arrow sidebar-link" href="" aria-expanded="false"><i class="mdi mdi-playlist-plus"></i> <span class="hide-menu">Menu 1.3</span></a>
                <ul aria-expanded="false" class="collapse second-level">
                  <li class="sidebar-item"><a href="" class="sidebar-link"><i class="mdi mdi-octagram"></i><span class="hide-menu"> item 1.3.1</span></a></li>
                  <li class="sidebar-item"><a href="" class="sidebar-link"><i class="mdi mdi-octagram"></i><span class="hide-menu"> item 1.3.2</span></a></li>
                  <li class="sidebar-item"><a href="" class="sidebar-link"><i class="mdi mdi-octagram"></i><span class="hide-menu"> item 1.3.3</span></a></li>
                  <li class="sidebar-item"><a href="" class="sidebar-link"><i class="mdi mdi-octagram"></i><span class="hide-menu"> item 1.3.4</span></a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="sidebar-item"><a href="" class="sidebar-link"><i class="mdi mdi-playlist-check"></i><span class="hide-menu"> item 1.4</span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar-footer">
      <a href="" class="link" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Settings"><i class="ti-settings"></i></a>
      <a href="" class="link" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Email"><i class="mdi mdi-gmail"></i></a>
      <a href="" class="link" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Logout"><i class="mdi mdi-power"></i></a>
    </div>
  </aside>
  <div class="page-wrapper">

    <!--<router-outlet></router-outlet>-->

    <footer class="footer">
      © 2020 Monster Admin by wrappixel.com
    </footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do the templates look like? Any console errors?

Comment: I already added the expected result image. and there is no console error

Comment: I have added index html and main layout component html as well. do you need something more?

Comment: My guess is that `jQuery` is doing something to the DOM that `angular` doesn't see  (or vice versa). It's pretty strongly recommended that you don't mix the two because of conflicting paradigms. Try removing it from the project and see if the problem resolves.  See the accepted answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54502849/what-is-the-impact-if-we-use-the-jquery-plugins-in-angular-7 for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @The Head Rush for putting me right direction. I m using a bootstrap theme which is not designed for Angular. After digging some Theme js files, I saw some code which is using jQuery code to implement some classes on runtime based on Theme selection. I just called its theme setting function back again, and its works. In my mainlayout component init function, I added this code

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    $("#main-wrapper").AdminSettings();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you localStorage.getItem("token")? where you're use?.

If you use in the MainLayoutComponent  I imagine you get in the ngOnInit of this component.

If you're use in other component -perhafs in the main.component that is who has the `<router-outlet>`- already loaded you **need indicate to Angular that localStorage has changed**. Generally you can use a Subject of one service. That's:

Imagine you has a service. As you should makes all the calls in a service, not in a component, you can have a services like

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class LoginService {
  login$:Subject<bool>=new Subject<bool>()
  constructor(private httpClient:HttpClient) { }

  login(model:any)
  {
      return this.httpClient.post<any>(Common.APIUrl + "login", model, { withCredentials: true })
       .pipe(tap(()=>{
            this.login$.next(true); //<--makes subject "next"
       })
      );
     
  }
  logout()
  {
    return this.httpClient.get<any>(Common.APIUrl + "logout", { withCredentials: true })
       .pipe(tap(()=>{
            this.login$.next(false); //<--makes subject "next"
       })
    )
  }
```

See that the functions return an observable -the call to your API-

When you subscribe to your LoginService -replace the httpClient.get by this.loginService.login() and this.loginService.logout()-

```
  SubmitForm() {
    if ($("#myloginform").parsley().validate()) {
      $(".preloader").show();
      this.loginService.login(this.submitModel)
        .subscribe(
         {
            ..your code..
         })
      );
    }
  }
```

And

```
Logout() {
    $(".preloader").show();
    this.loginService.logOut().subscribe(
      {
         ...your code
      }
    );
  }
```

See that, the "subject" change. So in the component where you need the information of the token you can subscribe to this subject and read the token

```
this.loginService.login$.subscribe((res:boolean)=>{
    ..make something to updte the "login"
})
```

Comment: I appreciated your efforts. I already know about service.ts, and I will move all API calls to separate service.ts file. I used localStorage just to save token in browser level, to pass this token in APIs header. This is not the issue here now. Even I remove the API call and simply redirecting on button click to another page. Still the same