# Page not loading js in angular until full page refresh

Tags: angular

**Issue Details**

I am trying to load js in component but it does not load js until page is refreshed manually.

Am I missing anything in below code?

I have already checked this url: [Page is not displaying properly until manually refresh Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71683409/page-is-not-displaying-properly-until-manually-refresh-angular)

but not helpful for me.

**Code in app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import "../assets/js/bootstrap-show-password.min.js";

@Component({

    selector: 'app-root',

    templateUrl: './app.component.html',

    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']

})

export class AppComponent {
    title = 'angular';
}
```

Please notice the above js reference, it works fine when I refresh the page but does not fine for buttons with `routerLink` attribute

Issue remains even if the above js reference is moved to a specific component.