# DOM manipulation in angular with packages that access DOM directly

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6

so I know that it is not recommended to access DOM directly from an angular application instead I should use Renderer and ElementRef to access the DOM,,
I already do that in my app,,

but what about the packages that I use that access the DOM using

```
document.getElementById
```

so is that okay?
, and if it's okay that means that I can access DOM directly too?

so a lot of confusion here please clarify ..

Comment: still looking for an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53451918/why-not-to-interact-with-the-dom-directly-in-angular?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

This is a Security risk work if you access dom directly. Please read more from [here](https://angular.io/api/core/ElementRef) and [here](https://angular.io/guide/security).

**Try to use the following code**

```
import { Inject }  from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common'; 

@Component({...})
export class AppShohel {
   constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) document) {
      document.getElementById('element');
   }
}
```

[Demo:](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-domelement-finding)

Comment: my question is about packages that access DOM directly is that okay or not,, and if okay why can't I just use document.getElementById as well

Comment: Ok let me think agian