# how to resize base64 image in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, base64, resize

i try to resize base64 image But I did not find an answer. I tried canvas but did not answer. I do not know why ...
This was the code

```
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas'),
             ctx = <CanvasRenderingContext2D>canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.width = 100;
        canvas.height = 100;
        const img = new Image();
        img.src = this.SelectedFile.src;
        ctx.drawImage(img , 0, 0, 100, 100);
        this.SelectedFile.src = ctx.canvas.toDataURL();
```

Does anyone know any other way or knows what the problem is?

Comment: Not a good idea to modify the DOM directly when using Angular. Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53451918/why-not-to-interact-with-the-dom-directly-in-angular

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Add this helper function outside of the given component:

```
function compressImage(src, newX, newY) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = src;
    img.onload = () => {
      const elem = document.createElement('canvas');
      elem.width = newX;
      elem.height = newY;
      const ctx = elem.getContext('2d');
      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, newX, newY);
      const data = ctx.canvas.toDataURL();
      res(data);
    }
    img.onerror = error => rej(error);
  })
}
```

Then call like so:

```
compressImage(base64, 100, 100).then(compressed => {
  this.resizedBase64 = compressed;
})
```

Comment: nvm, just saw there's a parameter for that in toDataURL()

Answer (score -3):

This code worked for me when trying to resize base64 images in angular libraries / HTML:

```
<style>
    .scaled {
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        transform-origin: left;
        transform: scale(1);
    }
</style>

<div class="scaled">
 <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVB....."></img>
</div>
```

Comment: When doing it this way, the image isn't resized, only on the UI.  It takes up much more bandwidth serving a full-size image versus one that has been resized directly.