# How can I resize an image before uploading via form input in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, image, upload, resize

I tried resizing an image before uploading and sometimes it works and sometimes not.

```
<form [formGroup]="uploadForm" (ngSubmit)="upload()">
  <input type="file" id="file" formControlName="file" (change)="onImageChange($event)">
  <div class="contentMainInput" *ngIf="imgFile">
    <img [src]="imgFile" style="height:100px">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" [disabled]='!uploadForm.valid'>Upload</button>
</form>
```

```
  onImageChange(e: any) {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    if(e.target.files && e.target.files.length) {
      const imgfile = e.target.files[0];
      reader.readAsDataURL(imgfile);
      reader.onload = () => {
        this.imgSrc = reader.result as string;
        const img = document.createElement("img");
        const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        img.src = this.imgSrc;
        canvas.width = 100;
        canvas.height = 100;
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d") as CanvasRenderingContext2D;
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 100, 100); // image resize to 100x100
        this.dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 1.0);
        this.imgFile = this.dataUrl; // bind with a preview-div
        this.uploadForm.patchValue({
          imgSrc: this.dataUrl
        });
      };
    }
  }
```

I guess if i put some console.log in the code it works frequent.

I also tried it with img.onload, but then I have no access to global variables like this.uploadForm.

So I'm looking for a code to do this:

- an image can be selected by a form
- the image will be resized
- the resized image will be previewed at the site
- the resized image gets uploaded after submitting

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work well now:

```
onImageChange(e: any) {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  if(e.target.files && e.target.files.length) {
    const imgfile = e.target.files[0];
    reader.readAsDataURL(imgfile);
    reader.onload = async () => {
      await this.resizeImage(reader.result as string).then((resolve: any) => {
        this.imgFile = resolve;
        this.uploadForm.patchValue({
          imgSrc: resolve
        });
      });
    };
  }
}

resizeImage(imageURL: any): Promise<any> {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const image = new Image();
    image.onload = function () {
      const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.width = 200;
      canvas.height = 200;
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      if (ctx != null) {
        ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 200, 200);
      }
      var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1);
      resolve(data);
    };
    image.src = imageURL;
  });
}
```

Comment: Modifying the DOM when using Angular is a big no-no. You are bypassing the Angular change detection system and adding security risks. Please, don't do that. Check this out for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53451918/why-not-to-interact-with-the-dom-directly-in-angular

Comment: @Pizzicato He's not modifying the DOM, he's creating a Canvas element dynamically. Doesn't even touch the document. As for the URL, it's a Data URL so it's the file that's on the local device already.

Comment: HI, yes, you are right, I didn't notice that the created element is not attached to the DOM after creating it. Sorry!